# Is it possible to take out only 1 file from a set of files that had been stashed using Git?

Tags: git, git-stash

I have `git stash save` some files, however I would like to take from that stash only 1 file out and leave the rest save.

Is this possible and how? I know of `git stash [pop|drop] ...` but my knowledge extends to there only.

Comment: `git checkout stash@{0} -- <filename>`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks for the answers, and oops sorry didn't realized it was a duplicate. Thanks